# How to add the allUsers member in cloud run using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I would like to add the `allUsers` member to a `google_cloud_run_service` with the Cloud Run Invoker role automatically using Terraform.

To get around this:

> Only authenticated invocations are allowed for this service. To allow
> unauthenticated invocations, add "allUsers" as a member and assign it
> the "Cloud Run invoker" role.

I don't have any issue adding the `allUsers` member manually and setting the role to Cloud Run Invoker.

But I was hoping that this could be done with Terraform.

I tried the following:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}
# Enable public access on Cloud Run service
resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  location = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}
```

But it does not seem to create the `allUsers` member after applying `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`.

Update:

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = "= 0.14.7"
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "mybucket-terraform-test"
    prefix = "backend"
  }
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 3.42.0"
    }
  }
}
```

foo.tf

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "project_name-cloudrun"
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "admin-account-iam" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"

  members = [
    "user:user@myorg.com",
  ]
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "myproject-backend"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    spec {
      service_account_name = "myproject-cloudrun@myproject-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      containers {
        image = "us.gcr.io/myproject-dev/myproject/myproject-backend@sha256:abc123"
      }
    }
  }
}

## not working as expected ##

data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}

##
```

Comment: @JohnHanley It did not make a difference. Also in this example from terraform it is not specified as a group. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#example-usage---cloud-run-service-noauth

Comment: In my Terraform Cloud Run code, I use `resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "allUsers" {
  service  = google_cloud_run_service.my-service.name
  location = google_cloud_run_service.my-service.location
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
}`

Comment: When I see problems like your where examples do not work, it is often the version of Terraform and the Provider that is the source of the problem. I am just guessing in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway! I tried your second comment as well without success. I have the latest version.. Terraform v0.14.7, using macosx.

Comment: I am using 0.14.5. If my example does not work, then you have something else going on in your Terraform code. Post the entire `.tf` masking any secrets, removing comments, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley Okay, sure, I edited :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229482/discussion-between-isbister-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Your .tf is too complex to visually debug. Create a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure, stripped out things that were not so related..

Comment: Was this resolved in chat? Unfortunately the chat has disappeared.